# How to update/overwrite a csv file currently imported in R

Tags: r, csv, overwrite

I'm trying to overwrite a csv file using `write_csv`. This works fine until I try to overwrite a file that I imported in R beforehand. For instance, running

```
dummy_df <- read_csv("dummy_data.csv")

dummy_df_2 <- dummy_df %>%
  mutate(ones = 1)

write_csv(dummy_df_2, "dummy_data.csv")
```

will return this error:

```
Error: Cannot open file for writing:
* 'D:\dummy_name_of_project_directory\dummy_data.csv'
```

(note that you won't encounter this error if you created the dummy_data.csv file in the same R session. I had to close Rstudio and open it again to encounter the error). The csv is not opened.

Removing `dummy_df` from the environment (using `rm()`) before trying to save `dummy_df_2` doesn't solve the problem.

I don't think I had this problem before, so I reckon something changed during the last update of R. I'm running on R version 4.1.1, and Rstudio version 1.4.1717.

Do you have any idea how to circumvent this error?

Thanks !

Comment: Run `getwd()`... What do you get? Maybe you need to `setwd()` first

Comment: is the CSV open?

Comment: @Sotos, the wd is the correct one. The error message I get specifies the correct wd. I replaced it by "D.\wd\" when writing my question for clarity. I'll change the formulation to make it clearer.

Comment: @Paladinic, no the csv is not opened. I should have specified it in my question.

Comment: Do you have permission to alter that file? Maybe try running R as admin

Comment: If running R as admin works, that is insightful, but then you really need to find a better solution that does not involve running in a superuser context: *change the ownership/permissions on the file*. (I'd recommend doing that before running R as admin.)

Comment: Are there any open connections:  `showConnections(); closeAllConnections()` ?  If you use read.csv instead of read_csv does that work?

Comment: @Sotos, I do have permission to alter that file (I can overwrite dummy_data.csv from Rstudio provided that I haven't imported dummy_data.csv into Rstudio beforehand). I tried running as admin just in case but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I don't think there are any open connections. Running `showConnections()` returns `description class mode text isopen can read can write` whether or not I run `closeAllConnections` beforehand. read.csv doesn't work either. It returns the following error message `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection`

Answer (score 1):

Try and update *readr* (towards 2.1). I ran into the same problem and I think the error message has stopped now  - I couldn't get a concrete reproducible example working to be 100% sure.

I think the problem is related to lazy reading in *readr* 2.0: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/11/readr-2-1-0-lazy/